# How to use @BeforeStep Job Parameters in JdbcCursorItemReader for named Query

Tags: spring-batch

I have the code like below

```
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> itemReader() {
    return new JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>>() {
        private JobParameters jobParameter;
        String sql = "select EMPLOYEE_ID as empId, EMPLOYEE_NAME as empName EMPLOYEE_AGE as age from EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE_DEPT =:empDept and EMPLOYEE_SAL > :empSal";
        Map<String, Object> namedParameters = null;
        @PostConstruct
        public void initialize() throws Exception
        {
            setDataSource(dataSource);
            setSql("select 1 from dual");
            setRowMapper(new ColumnMapRowMapper());
        }
        @BeforeStep
        public void retrieveExecutionContext(StepExecution stepExecution)
        {
            jobParameter = stepExecution.getJobParameters();
            namedParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
                {
                    put("bstd", jobParameter.getString("empDept"));
                    put("bwtn", jobParameter.getString("empSal"));
                }
            };
            jobParameter.getParameters().forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("key =" + k + ", Value:" + v));
        }
        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            setSql(NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(sql, new MapSqlParameterSource(namedParameters)));
            setPreparedStatementSetter(new ListPreparedStatementSetter(
                    Arrays.asList(NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(sql, namedParameters))));
            setRowMapper(new ColumnMapRowMapper());
            setDataSource(dataSource);
            super.afterPropertiesSet();
        }
    };
}
```

Tried using calling afterPropertiesSet, but still seeing below exception

> Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'empDept': No value registered for key 'empDept'
> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(NamedParameterUtils.java:361) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(NamedParameterUtils.java:485) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

Requirement is dynamic query, so don't have control of the Select query and the where conditions.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SpEL expression to inject and use job parameters in your item reader bean definition as follows:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> itemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['empDept']}") String empDept, @Value("#{jobParameters['empSal']}") String empSal) {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    // use parameters 'empDept' and 'empSal' in your sql query as needed
    return itemReader;
}
```

Note that the item reader should be step-scoped for that to work. For more details, please refer to the documentation: [Late Binding of Job and Step Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#late-binding).

Comment: This works fine if there is a constant where clause conditions, but if we want dynamic approach, this may not work, any alternatives for it

Comment: The same idea can be applied to dynamically add any part of the query. It really depends on the source of "dynamism" you are looking for, ie from where you will read the moving part of the query (job parameters, execution context, another method on a bean, etc), and this is where the power of SpEL comes in: whatever the source of your dynamic query, you can find it and inject it in your item reader bean definition with a SpEL expression.

Comment: I may be naive here, but the example you provided earlier has the 'empDept' and 'empSal' and that is pre configured, so can we override that method arguments as  in some scenarios, i will have only 'empDept' and in some cases only 'empSal' and in other cases both or extra will be added, We have another layer to get these parameters and will feed before calling the job launcher